# Reading file and making into dictionary with the values as a list of integers

Tags: python, dictionary

I have a file in the format shown below.

```
    A 83 140 228 286 426 612 486 577 836 0 0
    Aaliyah 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 380 215
    Aaron 193 208 218 274 279 232 132 36 32 31 41
    Abagail 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 958
    Abbey 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 537 451 428
    Abbie 431 552 742 924 0 0 0 0 752 644 601
    Abbigail 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 953 562
    Abby 0 0 0 0 0 906 782 548 233 211 209
    Abdiel 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 925 721
    Abdul 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 903 0 0 0
    Abdullah 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 1000 863
    Abe 248 328 532 764 733 0 0 0 0 0 0
    Abel 664 613 626 575 542 491 497 422 381 385 354
    Abigail 0 0 0 0 854 654 615 317 150 50 14
    Abigale 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 959
```

How would I be able to make a dictionary with the name as the key and the list of integers following each name as values?

Comment: Your question was not very clear - I have edited it (including the title) to say what I think you intended (and the answers have assumed).  If this is not what you meant - please edit it to give a more precise version of what you meant.  Please read the read the [how to ask](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) page carefully - you'll get much better help here if you follow that guide carefully and if you show what code you've attempted and how it failed.

Answer (score 5):

Pretty straightfoward:

```
d = {}
with open('file.txt') as f:
    for line in f:
        parts = line.split()
        d[parts[0]] = map(int, parts[1:])
```

The result is a dictionary `d`, keyed on the first token of each line, with a list of integers as the dictionary values.

Answer (score 1):

Since each name is followed by many numbers, I imagine you want a `dict` from the name to a `list` of `int` values...:

```
thedict = {}
with open(filename) as f:
    for line in f:
        pieces = line.strip().split()
        thedict[pieces[0]] = [int(p) for p in pieces[1:]]
```